# when removing a point from a closed set is still a closed set

Tags: general-topology

What are the criteria for such that if you remove a point x, from a set A such that A{x} is still closed. We are working on the Real numbers here with standard topology.

The only solution I can think of is if a closed set is some kind of closed interval union with some isolated point, then removing that isolated point should leave the set closed. Also a singleton set is closed and if you remove the only element in the set, you get the empty set which is still closed. So this leads me to believe that if you remove a isolated point from a closed set, it is always still a closed set. Am I correct or are there counterexamples?

Answer (score 1):

Given that $A$ is closed, $A-\{x\}$ is closed iff x is an isolated point of $A$, as in, there is some open neighbourhood $u$ of $x$ so that $u \cap A = \{x\}$. To see this, if for every open neighbourhood $u$ of $x$ there is some $x \neq y \in A$ we can choouse $u_n = (x-\frac{1}{n}, x+\frac{1}{n}),  y_n \in u_n \cap (A-\{x\})$ and note that $y_n$ converges to $x$, so $A-\{x\}$ can't be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Correct:(when $X \in A$) $A\setminus\{x\}$ is closed when $A$ is closed iff $x$ is isolated in $A$. The proof is obvious (what if $x$ is *not*?)