# Removing a point from closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm reading the proof for removing a point from closed set here;
[when removing a point from a closed set is still a closed set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885731/when-removing-a-point-from-a-closed-set-is-still-a-closed-set)

I'm confused about the conclusion. Given that we know that $y_n$ converges to $x$ (because of definition of limit point), why can't $A - \{x\}$ be closed? I think I am missing something here.

Comment: If the point is isolated then any sequence that converges to $x$ is equal to $x$ for all but a finite number of values.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you don't understand about the answers to the question you cite,

Comment: @RobArthan I don't understand why, if $x$ is isolated, $A - \{x\}$ will be closed. I understand it intuitively (i.e., drawing on arbitrary set on the real line) but don't see how to connect it to the linked proofs. 

My idea is that if x were not isolated, then A - {x} would have to have intervals [a, x) and (x, b]

Comment: That's the opposite of what you said in the body of your question. For the point in your comment: if $x$ is isolated, it has a neighbourhood $U$ that is disjoint from $A$. No sequence of points in $A$ meets $U$, so no sequence of points in $A$ can have $x$ as its limit.

Comment: @RobArthan So, as we know that no sequence of points in $A$ can have $x$ as its limit because $x$ is isolated, why does that mean $A - \{x\}$ is closed? I am just having trouble rigorously writing out why $A- \{x\}$ is closed - I don't know what the limit points of $A - \{x\}$ are, so I can't claim that it contains all its limit points and is thus closed..

Comment: You are given that $A$ is closed. So you know enough about its limit points to find the limit points of $A - \{x\}$.

Comment: @RobArthan since $A$ is closed, it has all its limit points let's call them $x_1, x_2, \ldots$.  $x$ is isolated and thus not a limit point, so when we have the set $A - \{x\}$, it still retains all the limit points $x_1, x_2, \ldots$. As a result, since $A- \{x\}$ has all its limit points, it is closed - is this the right idea?

Comment: Your idea is right, but the way you stated it suggests that the set of limit points of $A$ is countable, which need not be the case. Better to say "let $X$ be the set of limit points of $A$, then $x$ is isolated, so $x \not\in A$, ...$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y_n \to x$ where all $y_n \in A$ and $y_n \neq x$, this shows that $x$ is in the closure of $A-\{x\}$, as every neighbourhood of $x$ contains points of $A-\{x\}$ but not in $A-\{x\}$ so that set is strictly smaller than its closure (so not itself closed). Or $x \in (A-\{x\})'$ which shows that $A-\{x\}$ does not contain all its limit points (this is sometimes used as the definition of closed as well).

Comment: What do you mean by " as every neighbourhood of x contains points of A−{x} but not in A−{x} "? But the second explanation (Or...) does make sense, thank you!

Comment: @a6623 The closure of $A$ is all points $x$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $A$ and a set is closed iff it equals its closure.